# htaccess redirect everything except index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have removed the blog from my domain and put a simple index.html instead.
How do I redirect all the incoming traffic so that it does not show a 404 error, but redirects to the index?

I tried this, but it loops...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

As you mentioned that this doesn't work, I'd try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/aaa.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /aaa.html [L,R=301]
```

index.html is a general default file name, so there might be rules that are on the server level, not in your .htaccess. That depends on the server setup, though.

Comment: It does not work. If I go here it shows a redirect loop error. http://invalid.org/category/catname

Comment: I just tried it locally and it worked fine. Is this the only rewriting rule on the server? Can you try something else, like changing both index.html to aaa.htm?

Comment: wget -O- localhost/category/catname
--2010-11-13 10:56:44--  http://localhost/category/catname
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost/index.html [following]
--2010-11-13 10:56:44--  http://localhost/index.html
Reusing existing connection to localhost:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 177 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
</body></html>
2010-11-13 10:56:44 (7.95 MB/s) - written to stdout [177/177]

Comment: It is the only rewrite rule, yes. There are no other htaccess files. I cannot even open the index.html directly without getting a loop error.

Comment: You still need the RewriteCond as you originally specified - without it, you will always rewrite, which will generate a loop you are experiencing. There might be other rules on the server level - that's why I'd try changing index.html to aaa.html on both lines and trying, of course after renaming the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

at the very top and give it a try.