# .htaccess - Redirect all the pages after domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all the php pages after the domain in to username.php?un=.
For an example, if the user requested `http://example.com/username` then the page will be redirected to username.php.

I tried with following htaccess code. but it not works for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule /(.*)$ username.php?un=$1 [L]
```

This domain is used to show only user information. so there are only 2 pages will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this .htaccess code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username.php?un=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username.php?un=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username.php?un=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That means all urls include the index, open the `username.php` file with the GET - parameter "un" (`$_GET["un"]`). In the `$_GET["un"]` you find the normal url.

**Edit**: only HTML files are in this rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)+\.html$ username.php?un=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)+\.html$ username.php?un=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)+\.html$ username.php?un=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is that possible for use above code for except index.php or index.html

Comment: Yes change the Rewrite Rule `^(.*)$`  lines to `^(.*)+\.php$` so only the php files are in this rule, or **html** instead of **php**

Comment: Richard, thanks it works.. but i need a small change in ur code. i want redirection except index.php.

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173165/htaccess-redirect-everything-except-index-page

Comment: Thanks Richard.. now it works good..also i accepted your answer.. keep coding.. :-)

Comment: Just curious why all the `.html` in the _patterns_? The OP gave `http://example.com/username` as an example of the request and clarified this with "**except** index.php or index.html". Also, the second rule will never match either as the preceding condition will never match. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+) username.php?un=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Access forbidden!
 Error 403

Comment: I am not sure why you getting this may be some other rule in config file is working but for the redirection part it is working if you see [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=918d51b9-81b7-563b-a512-cf55be1702d9)

Comment: The 403 error is because this is a _redirect_, not a _rewrite_, and there is no slash prefix on the _substitution_, so the directory-prefix is added. But this would also result in a redirect loop if the first redirect was successful.